# Can I use the google satellite layer with mapboxgl?

Tags: google-maps, mapbox

I can't find any mention of this on the internets, is it possible to use google maps satellite with mapboxgl? has anyone done it? we have an account with google maps but they never answer :(

Comment: No. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1791

Comment: But that is from 2015 and that clause no longer appears in the license? https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/?hl=en#10-license-restrictions

Comment: Thx for the question! I was just about to ask the same :) Which alternative to goole map sat-tiles did you end up using? Mapbox-Sat tiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Google Maps Terms of Service section 3.2.4d](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license)

> 3.2.4 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services.
>
> (d) No Use With Non-Google Maps. Customer will not use the Google Maps
>   Core Services in a Customer Application that contains a non-Google
>   map. For example, Customer will not (i) display Places listings on a
>   non-Google map, or (ii) display Street View imagery and non-Google
>   maps in the same Customer Application.

This also covers your inquiry as you will use the Google Maps Satellite Layer with other products outside of Google Maps APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Our confusion comes from the definition of what "a non-Google map" is.
We are proposing to use the mapping framework Mapbox-GL to show only Google Satellite tiles.

The examples given only seem to say that you can't use Google map data with non-Google tilesets.

The intention of this section seems to be so that people do not confuse which parts are related to Google.

Can you please help us with the definition of "a non-Google map"?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, the "non-Google map" is actually pertaining to non-Google Maps products, which includes other maps provider like Mapbox as it is not a product of Google. This means that all Google Maps Product can only be used along with other Google Maps products and should not be associated with non-Google maps products. :)